# Can the domain of one FQDN itself be a FQDN?

Tags: hostname, fqdn

Is it valid to name two machines such that:

- Machine-1: Room1.BuildingA.MyDomain.com
- Machine-2: BuildingA.MyDomain.com

Right now the machines are being named manually in their respective /etc/hosts files. Will this naming schema cause me any trouble down the line with other networking protocols, DNS

Answer (score 1):

Your two examples are FQDN. Each one can be a different entry on DNS.